# this() and this

Tags: java, this

Does Java has `this()`?

If so, what's the difference between `this` and `this()`?

Comment: you have asked the difference between `this` and `this()` then why you had choose

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`this` is reference to current instance. `this()` is call to default constructor. `super()` is *explicit* call to default constructor of super class.

Comment: so `super` is a reference to the super class?

Comment: @JJ Liu yep, that's correct. (: so you could call a protected/public super method explicitely by `super.aSuperMethod(var1, var2)`

Answer (score 8):

`this` is a reference to the current object. `this()` is a call to the default constructor; it is only legal inside another constructor, and only as the first statement in the constructor. You can also call `super()` to invoke the default constructor for the superclass (again, only as the first statement of a constructor). This is, in fact, automatically inserted by the compiler if there is no `this()` or `super()` (with or without arguments) present in the code. For instance:

```
public class A {
    A() {
       super(); // call to default superclass constructor.
    }

    A(int arg) {
        this(); // invokes default constructor
        // do something special with arg
    }

    A(int arg, int arg2) {
        this(arg); // invokes above constructor
        // do something with arg2
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, when you do `super()`, do you always call to the default no-argument superclass constructor?  I mean, when you say the default constructor, do you always mean the one with no argument?

Comment: @JJLiu - You can call `super(args)` if the superclass defines a constructor with args.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java has `this()`. `this()` calls the parameterless overload of the constructor for the current class. `this` is a reference to the current instance (object) of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a keyword in `java` used to hold the reference ID of current object.
While, `this()` is the call to the default constructor in your `java program`.

A code snippet for `this()`:

```
class ThisTest{
    ThisTest(){
        System.out.println("this is the default constructor of your class");
    }
    ThisTest(int val){
        this();
        System.out.println("this is the parameterized constructor of your class and the passed value is "+val);
    }
    public static void main(String...args){
        ThisTest tt=new ThisTest(10);
    }
}
```

In the above code you'd created an object of your class by using the parameterized constructor but `this()` must be the first in your any constructor to call any other constructor.
You can also change the above code to:

```
ThisTest(){
    this(10);
    //above code
}
ThisTest(int val){
    //above code
}
public static void main(string...args){
    ThisTest tt=new ThisTest();
}
```