# Purpose of this() in following code snippet?

Tags: java

```
package test;

public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;
    
    Employee() {}
    
    Employee(String newName, int newAge) {
        this();
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Employee e = new Employee("N", 43);
        System.out.println();
    }    
}
```

In the above code, what is the actual point of "this()" in the overloaded constructor from a usefulness perspective besides being an example of calling the no-argument constructor from the overloaded constructor?

Comment: I would assume, if someone subclasses `Employee` and modifies the no-args constructor, then it would get called even if they _didn't_ modify the constructor-with-arguments, but someone chose to use the constructor-with-arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [this() and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092046/this-and-this)

Comment: Hello Vishal....thanks for reaching out...i know the difference between this() and this...but i was asking within context of the code sample as to what functional purpose is served by putting "this()" in the overloaded constructor when the no-argument constructor has no special code to do anything..

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's the wrong way round to me.

A typical use of this() would be to provide a default value for the constructor when not supplied in the argument as you cannot call the constructor directly. Adapting your code for example:

package test;

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;

Employee() {
    this("Default", 42);
}

Employee(String newName, int newAge) {
    name = newName;
    age = newAge;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: Of course if the no argument constructor contains code that actually does something (not in the example in question) it might support processing used across a number of other constructors with arguments. This would be good coding style as the common code would be visibly shared through the use of this()

Comment: thanks mhaselup...just wanted to mention that the code was from a book and it was for demonstration purposes as an example....but in my head, i sort of suspect there is no real use to call the no-argument constructor using this() from the overloaded constructor ...because eventually the control is stepped back into the overloaded constructor

Answer (score 1):

In that exact snippet?

Literally nothing.

Any constructor MUST neccessarily have, at the top of it, either a `this()` call, or a `super()` call. You can't not. If you fail to write it, javac will inject: `super();` for you, and if that isn't valid (for example, your superclass does not have a protected+ no-args constructor), then your code won't compile.

So that's the difference between the snippet as pasted and a hypothetical one where the `this();` is removed. Desugaring, you get either:

### Desugared, WITHOUT the this():

```
package test;

public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;
    
    Employee() {
        super(); // invokes java.lang.Object's no-args, which does nothing.
    }
    
    Employee(String newName, int newAge) {
        super(); // invokes java.lang.Object's no-args, which does nothing.
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
    }
}
```

### Desugared, WITH the this():

```
package test;

public class Employee {
    String name;
    int age;
    
    Employee() {
        super(); // invokes java.lang.Object's no-args, which does nothing.
    }
    
    Employee(String newName, int newAge) {
        this();
        name = newName;
        age = newAge;
    }
}
```

Now, inject, say, a `System.out.println("Hello!");` in the no-args constructor and now there is a small difference: With the `this()`, you'd see `Hello!` printed, and without it, you won't. Either way, though, you end up calling your superclass's constructor, as that is something that has to happen, one way or another. (Only java.lang.Object doesn't have to, hardcoded in the VM; Object has no superclass).

Comment: thanks rzwitserloot...so i had another question...i ran this code through debug and traced the flow.... once this() is executed...it goes to the no argument constructor and then eventually back to the statement "name = newName" in the overloaded constructor...what is the point of then the "this()" within this context?.....to me..it serves no real purpose...except to perhaps maybe initialize the instance variables to their default values before being set to those through the overloaded constructor

Comment: I told you, right at the top: There is no point in this exact code. It only has effects if your no-args constructor or your superclass's no-args constructor actually does something.

Answer (score 0):

To call the default constructor, this() is used.